# wordpress theme configuration error? - localhost vs online

Tags: wordpress

the online dashboard is different with the localhost dashboard
but i already enter all the basic primary menu (home, design, contact...)
but how come it wont show up? like the online sample?

[image]

by the way, i'm just start learning wordpress
free themes from wordpress call [Goran]

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things in your online Wordpress installation.

1. please your theme settings that can be found under the appearance tab in Wordpress admin panel. These should be same as your online website.
2. Check what is the value of `Front page displays` option can be found under `setting > reading` option. Compare the local value with the online?